# user->setParam in onUserAfterSave plugin has no effect

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a (currently working) plugin which creates a user on a third party system when a user registers. This is working fine so far.

I'm trying now to add a param to the user to store the third party id but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
function onUserAfterSave($user,$isNew,$success,$msg=''){
        if(!$isNew || ! $success){
            return;
        }
        jimport('joomla.log.log');
        $res = someThirdPartyCall();
        //Res is valid here
        JLog::add("Res  ".print_r($res,true), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');


        $userOb = JUser::getInstance($user['id']);
        $userOb->setParam('sugarid', $res['id']);
        //User ob is valid here
        JLog::add("UserOb  ".print_r($userOb,true), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');
        $saveRes = $userOb->save();

         //Result is true. Error array is empty.
        JLog::add("Result ".print_r($saveRes,true), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');
        JLog::add("Errors ".print_r($userOb->getErrors(),true), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

    }
```

Everything looks great, no errors or the like. The only thing not working is that the params aren't set in the db. Is this because I'm trying to save the user in `onUserAfterSave`?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to **import** the user library in to your plugin to use `setParam`. So At the beginning of your file do not forget to include user library. Use this line of code.

```
jimport( 'joomla.user.user' );
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: JUser autoloads.  The only part that doesn't is JAuthenticate and you should do JLoader for that at this point since it's not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If save is finished you can't go back and add to it, the save is finished and door is shut. You need to do set things up when you set up the paramters by making a form plugin to add another field to the params.  Then you don't need to save at all because params will just save as part of the normal process. I'm assuming this is not something that needs to be encrypted, right? It's just the user name?

Also I should mention that there is Juser::defParam($key, $value)  that lets you add parameters via code.